# nginx and php-fpm socket owner

Tags: php, nginx, centos

After an update of my system I ran into a bad gateway error of my PHP apps running on Nginx.

> 1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-vhostname-php-fcgi-0.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-vhostname-php-fcgi-0.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"

The problem is caused by bad permissions of the php-fpm sockets used, in fact I see `/var/run/php-fcgi.sock` owned by `root:root` but nginx and php-fpm use as user `www-data`.

I've already edited the php-fpm config at `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` with:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

but it doesn't solve the problem and when i restart nginx and php-fpm the sockets are created with `root:root` as user/group.

The only way I've found to fix it is to change the owner of the sockets to www-data:www-data manually. But this is not a real solution because everytime I restart my services I've to apply it again.

How can I fix this problem? I'm on CentOS 6.5

### Edit:

I use Ajenti-V to configure my vhosts and my PHP-FPM. It creates a new socket for each website/vhost, and them are set in `/etc/php-fpm.conf`

They have this structure:

```
[vhostname-php-fcgi-0]
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php-fcgi-vhostname-php-fcgi-0.sock

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
```

If I add to each entry these strings:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0666
```

Everything works correctly.

So looks like the www.conf is not included (maybe?). This is my php-fpm.conf:

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log


[global-pool]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php-fcgi.sock

pm = dynamic
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.max_children = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5


[vhostname-php-fcgi-0]
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php-fcgi-vhostname-php-fcgi-0.sock

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
```

Comment: I've withdrawn my answer as it was incorrect. In my case 0666 was the solution because of different groups in nginx and php-fpm. But also I checked my installation (CentOS 6.5 as well) and I don't see this problem... `PHP 5.4.28 (cli) (built: May  2 2014 19:09:57)`

Comment: I've just updated my php version and the same - no such an issue. `PHP 5.4.29 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2014 16:07:48)`. The last thing that I can imagine is that www.conf is for some reason not used in your case.

Comment: yes I think it ignores these settings... but I've not idea about how to fix it.

Comment: **Hmm, try using pool setting.**

**Nginx Bad Gateway means its can't find php or php-fpm is busy.**

Please provide error log on **NGINX.**

Comment: I've added the error log, btw it's just what I've already explained...

Comment: In you error log socket-path - /var/run/php5-fpm.sock, but above you use path /var/run/php-fcgi.sock. Do yo have only one php-fpm server (files in /etc/php-fpm.d/) or in /etc/php-fpm.conf maybe declared other server or you have other include. If two php-fpm servers have same name, but different options you can see this situation.

Comment: I actually use one socket for each website (I use Ajenti-V to configure nginx and PHP). I've just edited the log string to remove the domain from the socket name. By the way in my php-fpm.conf I've user and group set to www-data on every socket.

Comment: Just like voodoo programming try change `global-pool` name to something else. `test` for example.

Comment: Changing it to test has no effects.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Config files FPM will read

`/etc/php-fpm.conf` is the config file FPM will read (on CentOS). If you want FPM to read other config files as well, you need to tell it that.

You can do this by placing the line `include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf` at the bottom of `/etc/php-fpm.conf`. It will then read everything in the directory `/etc/php-fpm.d` (that ends with `.conf`).

Then place the global directives and the include line in `/etc/php-fpm.conf`. This could look something like this:

```
[global]

pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log

include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

And have a separate file in `/etc/php-fpm.d` for each pool.

Example `/etc/php-fpm.d/global.conf`:

```
[global-pool]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php-fcgi.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

pm = dynamic
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.max_children = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
```

Example `/etc/php-fpm.d/vhostname-0.conf`:

```
[vhostname-php-fcgi-0]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php-fcgi-vhostname-php-fcgi-0.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
```

#### Directives to pay attention to

- Every pool should use a different socket. If you have multiple pools using the same socket you'll get issues.
- The directives `user` and `group` control the user/group which the FPM process for that pool will run as. These do *not* specify the user/group of the socket.
- The directives `listen.owner` and `listen.group` control the user/group the socket uses for that pool.
- The pool directives (like `listen.*`) will only work for pools. So you *can't* use them in the global section, you *have to* specify them for each pool.

#### Socket permissions

The permissions 0660 are perfectly fine when `listen.owner` and `listen.group` are the same as the webserver. You could even use 0600, but one might argue that any user that can operate under the same group as the webserver can also use the socket, so I would use 0660.

Comment: Thanks, but adding the include does not have effects... I'd like to declare globally the listen.parameters so I have not to add them to each socket configuration...

Comment: I'm not sure about what "effects" you're talking about here. In any case, I've edited my answer to be more clear on how FPM should be configured when using a different file for each pool.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that if you set "listen.acl_users", it will cause listen.owner and listen.group to be ignored. So if you can't figure out why it's not using your owner and group, check acl_users as well.

Answer (score 9):

NGINX runs as user `nginx` and php5-fpm as user `www-data`.  Just add `nginx` to group `www-data` and the problem is solved, and nginx can access `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.  Works great with Ubuntu 14.04, nginx 1.7.10, PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (fpm-fcgi):

```
$ sudo usermod -aG www-data nginx
```

Comment: I think it is changed to "apache" for nowadays, "www-data" is in Debian, but author says about CentOS.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding here that the `listen.acl_users` directive should be commented, otherwise, it will override the `listen.owner` and `listen.group` values:

```
; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

; When POSIX Access Control Lists are supported you can set them using
; these options, value is a comma separated list of user/group names.
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
;listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
```

Comment: best answer ever!

Answer (score 1):

everybody!
That's my issue too.
I just changed my fpm user to vagrant, restart my pools and ... it's done!
Here comes my conf:

```
user = vagrant
group = nginx

listen.owner = vagrant
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

Hope it can help someone.

Comment: Yeah, this is the key in case of using Vagrant

Answer (score 1):

**Just do it anything else**

My Config
Vagrant / Ubuntu 16 / Nginx 1.13 / PHP-FPM 7.1

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Change first line user nginx => user www-data

```
service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 1):

On my installation, Centos 7.5, Apache with php 7.1 and php 5.6 I had the same problem where I had to manually fix the permissions on the **php56-php.fpm.sock** (owned by root) after every reboot.

My config for php56 was here and may be different on your install:
**/opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf**

I changed this commented section in the file:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0666
```

Now after restart everything is fine with correct permissions on the socket file. Not sure about the listen.mode. I think **0660** also works.

Comment: You can also use listen.acl_users=nginx (and listen.mode=0666 is bad for security)

Comment: Thanks @RemiCollet for advice!

Answer (score 0):

Hello every one and thanks for help, in my case with Ubuntu server 14.04 nginx and php5-fpm the problem with php-fpm socket owner by root solved by editing the file /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
Uncomment the lines:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

From a clear installation nginx owner and group is www-data.
I think that the best practice is to look /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and verify that in first line is:

```
user www-data;
```

And use the default user, Chears !